# table that shows and let order products in prestashop

Tags: module, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am looking for an addon which allows me to make a table that allows clients to order my products from it. A simple and minimal excel table where there are all my products on the leftest column and each of the other columns represent a category ( quantity, price per kg, origin,date to pick up the product in my shop.. ). A client should be able to choose the quantity and other fields and place the order.

Does anything like this exsist?

I am running prestashop 1.6.1.10

Hope you'll understand

thanks

Lorenzo

Comment: Hello. This is a very specific development. I don't think already exist a module for this and in this site you probably won't find help. You must contact a developer ;) Good luck.

Comment: I think you can better ask this in de prestashop forum.

Comment: thanks anyway for your time